# Specifying the format in which I want to get a response through POST

Tags: architecture, web-services, rest, http

It's a good practice to let a client specify the format in Web REST API:

```
GET /api/items/123.csv
```

However, not only `GET` can return some answer, but `POST` also can do

```
Status: 201 Created

{
  mgs: "Your item has created successfully",
  href: "/example.com/items/123"
}
```

How should `URI` look like for a `POST` (`PUT` or whatever, but not `GET`) request which returns a response so that a client can specify the format they want the response to be in? Like this?:

```
POST /api/items/.csv
```

Or suppose there is an error when a client sends a POST request and the server must inform the client about it:

```
Status: 400 Bad Request
{
  mgs: "this is a bad request",
  devMessage: "it's bad because ...."
  friendlyMessage: "something bad happened..."
}
```

What format should it respond in, why and how do I specify it as a client?

P.S. - I'm aware about [REST - Tradeoffs between content negotiation via Accept header versus extensions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139654/rest-tradeoffs-between-content-negotiation-via-accept-header-versus-extensions)

Comment: POST /api/items.csv is another option? Since you are talking to the resource items?

Comment: The server isn't _required_ to respect the `Accept` header, especially when returning an error and not a 200, but it _should_ definitely try to get any `Content-Type` it sends back to actually describe what it is sending.

Answer (score 3):

```
POST /api/items/.csv
```

looks logical only if you give '.csv' special meaning. If not, then it should be interpreted as POST /api/items/.csv/ by the server which I don't think it's what you want. I'm just using this as example where using file extension doesn't work.

Regarding what should be returned, the server should look at the Accept header and respond in acceptable format if it returns any entity at all (4xx responses should return explanation why it was an error).

I think it should be like this:

```
POST /api/postbox/
Accept: application/json
Content-type: text/csv
```

If success server returns:

```
201 Created
Location: /api/items/123.csv
```

or when fail:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-type: application/json
Message-body: { error: "please only post text/csv file." }
```

Comment: The only thing wrong with this answer is that the resource is never `/api/items/.csv/`; that's totally different in general (even if your particular environment happens to make it the same).

Comment: @DonalFellows maybe it's not obvious, but I don't think it's wrong. I put the trailing '/' there to make it explicit that generally you _POST_ to a resource. If it were a PUT then, yes, it wouldn't be always the case. I also want to detach the file extension association from .csv identifier. Otoh, POST to /api/items/csv could also work if the designer decided that different media type is significant to different users (so he can have /api/items/csv/1.csv /api/items/csv/2.csv). An analogy is that it's common to have /api/help/en/index.html and /api/help/fr/index.html for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to addresses what to do when a client `GETs` *from* the server, *not* what to do when the client `POSTs` *to* the server.

In your case, the use of the HTTP `Accept` header won't work as it is the equivilent of a client saying: "Hey give me this resource, but only in these formats."

This is a case where the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) applies:

> Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others.

When the client `POSTs` the data there should be a [`Content-Type` that describes whats being delivered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). Where possible, your application should interpret and accept as much as possible before failing. Does it matter if its CSV, JSON, or XML if you application can accept all three?

A single URL for delivery will be easier on your clients, and most likely easier on you. Apart from a slight difference in code to pull the content from the CSV, JSON, XML, whatever, its most likely that once you convert it to a format the application handles internally the data will be treated the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send back an URL after a POST request? What's usually done is redirecting to the newly created resource. For example:

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: /example/items/123
```

All this in the headers.

Same for when an error happens, the status code is enough. `403 Forbidden` means what it says.

With regards to the POST URL, the other question definitely answers that.

Comment: the question is not about these 2 specific responses but about the general way. `Same for when an error happens, the status code is enough` this is not enough for sure since there are many other errors can occur.

Comment: what if it were `400 Bad Request`?

Comment: @Grienders how is `400 Bad Request` not enough?

Comment: read the question again.